# How can we create mixture density networks with MXNet?

Tags: r, regression, gaussian, mxnet, mixture

I am evaluating MXNet in R and I would like to model mixture density netowrks. An example with Tensorflow, Keras and Edward can be found here: http://cbonnett.github.io/MDN_EDWARD_KERAS_TF.html

The example shown is a mixture of Normal Distributions. How could one do the same analysis with MXNet?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no implementation of Mixture density networks (MDN) in MxNet yet. And, since MxNet is a community effort, you are more than welcome to contribute!

Migrating code from Keras/TF should be quite straightforward in your case. R bindings for MxNet are quite limited at the moment in terms that it is impossible for now to create custom operations, but looking into the example, I don't see that any custom operations would be required.

I haven't run this code, but here is how MDN model from your example would look like using MxNet Python Symbol API:

```
def mapping(self, X):
    """pi, mu, sigma = NN(x; theta)"""
    hidden1 = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=X, num_hidden=15)  # fully-connected layer with 15 hidden units
    act1 = mx.sym.Activation(data=hidden1, act_type='relu')
    hidden2 = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act1, num_hidden=15)  # fully-connected layer with 15 hidden units
    act2 = mx.sym.Activation(data=hidden2, act_type='relu')

    self.mus = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act2, num_hidden=self.K)  # fully-connected layer with 15 hidden units

    sigma_fc = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act2, num_hidden=self.K)
    self.sigmas = mx.sym.exp(data=sigma_fc) # the variance

    pi_fc = mx.sym.FullyConnected(data=act2, num_hidden=self.K)
    self.pi = mx.sym.SoftmaxActivation(data=pi_fc) # the mixture components
```